# Elastic Beanstalk error while deploying Django project

Tags: python, django, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I'm getting the following error.

```
[Tue Jan 21 16:04:55.908186 2020] [:error] [pid 2102] [remote 127.0.0.1:17592] mod_wsgi (pid=2102): Exception occurred processing WSGI script '/opt/python/current/app/vspmschool/vspmschool/wsgi.py'.
[Tue Jan 21 16:04:55.908338 2020] [:error] [pid 2102] [remote 127.0.0.1:17592] Traceback (most recent call last):
[Tue Jan 21 16:04:55.908382 2020] [:error] [pid 2102] [remote 127.0.0.1:17592]   File "/opt/python/current/app/vspmschool/vspmschool/wsgi.py", line 16, in <module>
[Tue Jan 21 16:04:55.908387 2020] [:error] [pid 2102] [remote 127.0.0.1:17592]     application = get_wsgi_application()
[Tue Jan 21 16:04:55.908393 2020] [:error] [pid 2102] [remote 127.0.0.1:17592]   File "/opt/python/run/venv/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/wsgi.py", line 12, in get_wsgi_application
[Tue Jan 21 16:04:55.908404 2020] [:error] [pid 2102] [remote 127.0.0.1:17592]     django.setup(set_prefix=False)
[Tue Jan 21 16:04:55.908410 2020] [:error] [pid 2102] [remote 127.0.0.1:17592]   File "/opt/python/run/venv/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 19, in setup
[Tue Jan 21 16:04:55.908413 2020] [:error] [pid 2102] [remote 127.0.0.1:17592]     configure_logging(settings.LOGGING_CONFIG, settings.LOGGING)
[Tue Jan 21 16:04:55.908419 2020] [:error] [pid 2102] [remote 127.0.0.1:17592]   File "/opt/python/run/venv/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 76, in __getattr__
[Tue Jan 21 16:04:55.908422 2020] [:error] [pid 2102] [remote 127.0.0.1:17592]     self._setup(name)
[Tue Jan 21 16:04:55.908427 2020] [:error] [pid 2102] [remote 127.0.0.1:17592]   File "/opt/python/run/venv/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 63, in _setup
[Tue Jan 21 16:04:55.908430 2020] [:error] [pid 2102] [remote 127.0.0.1:17592]     self._wrapped = Settings(settings_module)
[Tue Jan 21 16:04:55.908435 2020] [:error] [pid 2102] [remote 127.0.0.1:17592]   File "/opt/python/run/venv/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 142, in __init__
[Tue Jan 21 16:04:55.908438 2020] [:error] [pid 2102] [remote 127.0.0.1:17592]     mod = importlib.import_module(self.SETTINGS_MODULE)
[Tue Jan 21 16:04:55.908456 2020] [:error] [pid 2102] [remote 127.0.0.1:17592]   File "/opt/python/run/venv/lib64/python3.6/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
[Tue Jan 21 16:04:55.908458 2020] [:error] [pid 2102] [remote 127.0.0.1:17592]     return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
[Tue Jan 21 16:04:55.908463 2020] [:error] [pid 2102] [remote 127.0.0.1:17592]   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 994, in _gcd_import
[Tue Jan 21 16:04:55.908468 2020] [:error] [pid 2102] [remote 127.0.0.1:17592]   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load
[Tue Jan 21 16:04:55.908473 2020] [:error] [pid 2102] [remote 127.0.0.1:17592]   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 953, in _find_and_load_unlocked
[Tue Jan 21 16:04:55.908488 2020] [:error] [pid 2102] [remote 127.0.0.1:17592] ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'vspmschool.settings'
```

My app name is vspmschool. Every thing works correctly on local system. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: often discrepancies between environments with ModuleNotFoundErrors is a result of different working directories, ensure that elastic beanstalk is starting from the same directory you are locally.

Comment: @OsmosisJonesLoL How do I ensure that?

Comment: Please help me. I'm at my wit's end.

Comment: I'm not familiar enough with elastic beanstalk's environment to help you too much, however here is some debugging advice. You can see the stack trace within your wsgi.py file, try adding some debugging logs that list the working directory or what files are in your working directory. Often to solve this problem people just need to change their DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE environment variable, however there's likely EBS specific configurations you might want to research as well that could help.

Comment: You need to set `DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE` environment variable.

Comment: Post the structure of your project. By doubling up `vspmschool` I have a feeling your settings path is `vspmschool.vspmschool.settings` and EB is looking under `vspmschool.settings`